# Mapped drives are slow

Tags: windows, networking, windows-explorer

I am running Windows XP and when I click to open a mapped drive it takes ages to open. This happens only on the first mapped drive selected each day; once the first drive has been successfully opened, any other drive selected after that will open without delay. It’s OK on non-mapped drives; this delay doesn’t happen with them. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3):

Mapped drives will be slow the first time because Windows needs to re-establish the network connection.  The next time, it already has it.

Comment: You may also be the first person hitting the mapped drive location.  If so the HD's probably went to sleep, and you have to wake them up before they can be accessed.  This with Nicole answer is why they are slower for the first time.  This happens on my home NAS as I tell it to sleep after 15mins of inactivity.